# How do I set SessionConfiguration permission for PowerShell remoting using SDDL?

Tags: powershell, security, powershell-remoting, winrm

I am trying to allow remote access for a user to a machine through `WINRM`.

Somewhere on the internet, I found out that this will need modification of RootSDDL for the `WINRM` configuration, and the value of it could be fetched like this:

```
(Get-Item WSMAN:\localhost\Service\RootSDDL).Value

O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-21-XXXXX-1889625497-1141)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GWGX;;;WD)
```

Now the question is the following: When I know the `SID` of the user I want to allow PowerShell remoting, how do I change the `Security Descriptor` by adding an `ACE` like `(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-21-The-rest-of-my-user-SID)` ?

Is there any code snippets to parse `SDDL` into array of `ACE`:s, modify it and parse it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code isn't completely working, but if you fix the constructor parameters (in the `$ArgumentList` variable) for the `ObjectAce` object, you should be able to get it working. I'll try to come back to this a bit later and finish it off.

This example does show how to use the `RawSecurityDescriptor` class to "import" SDDL, and then call the `GetSDDLForm()` method to "export" it back to SDDL. All we need to figure out is how to properly construct the `ObjectAce` object, and call `InsertAce()` to add it to the `RawSecurityDescriptor` object, before we export it to SDDL.

```
# Create a Security Descriptor from SDDL
$SD = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.RawSecurityDescriptor -ArgumentList 'O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-21-3231263931-1371906242-1889625497-1141)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GWGX;;;WD)';

# Add a new Access Control Entry
# ObjectACE constructor docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectace.objectace(v=vs.110).aspx
$ArgumentList = @(
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AceFlags]::None,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.AceQualifier]::AccessAllowed,
    1,
    [System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectAceFlags]::None,
    )
$ObjectACE = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectAce -ArgumentList $ArgumentList;
$SD.DiscretionaryAcl.InsertAce($ObjectACE);

# Convert the Security Descriptor back into SDDL
$SD.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All);
```

Comment: You mean that this is lacking proper AccessMask? I found funtion  Get-AccessMaskFromPermission here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/07/27/scripting-wmi-namespace-security-part-3-of-3.aspx

Comment: Good find - sorry, I had to run off to an appointment before I could finish filling out the thought.

Comment: Still your answer was helpfull, and you could finish writing it for future use. ;)

Comment: The `Get-AccessMaskFromPermission` isn't available anymore on that MSDN link. But it can be found at WayBack Machine [WMI Blog - Scripting WMI Namespace Security](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104183233/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wmi/archive/2009/07/27/scripting-wmi-namespace-security-part-3-of-3.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Using information from the Trewor Sullivan's answer I managed to add this with following code:

```
function add_sid_with_A_GA($sddl, $sid) {
    $security_descriptor = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor -ArgumentList @($false, $false, $sddl);

    $security_descriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess("Allow", $sid, 268435456,"None","None")

    # Convert the Security Descriptor back into SDDL
    $security_descriptor.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All);
}
```

`268435456` is the AccessMask for GA rights.

Answer (score 0):

To work with a `Security Descriptor` using `SDDL` (Security Descriptor Definition Language) you first need to know the structure.

From [MS Learn - Security Descriptor String Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-descriptor-string-format)

> The format is a null-terminated string with tokens to indicate each of the four main components of a security descriptor:
>
> - owner (O:),
> - primary group (G:),
> - DACL (D:),
> - and SACL (S:)

**DACL (Discretionary Access Control List)**

A `DACL` is a list of Access Control Entries (ACEs) that dictates who can access a specific object and what actions they can perform with it.

The term "discretionary" implies that the object’s owner has control over granting access and defining the level of access.

**SACL (System Access Control List)**

A `SACL` is a set of Access Control Entries (ACEs) that specify the security events to be audited for users or system processes attempting to access an object. These objects can include files, registry keys, or other system resources.

**Structure of a Security Descriptor**

This is a simple example of a `Security Descriptor` string in `SDDL`

```
"O:LAG:BUD:(A;;RPWPCCDCLCSWRCWDWOGA;;;S-1-5-32-545)"
```

- O:owner_sid
- G:group_sid (primary group)
- D:dacl_flags(string_ace1)(string_ace2)... (string_acen)
- S:sacl_flags(string_ace1)(string_ace2)... (string_acen)

When assigning permissions you are using the `DACL` part of the `Security Descriptor`.
Every entry in a `Security Descriptor` is called an `ACE` (Access Control Entry).

This particular example doesn't have a SACL (S: is missing).
Instead of SID:s for O: and G:, the constants `LA` (Local Administrator) and `BU` (Builtin Users) are used.

See [MS Learn - SID Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sid-strings)

```
ConvertFrom-SddlString "O:AOG:AOD:(A;;RPWPCCDCLCSWRCWDWOGA;;;S-1-5-32-545)"


Owner            : EXAMPLEHOST\Administrator
Group            : BUILTIN\Users
DiscretionaryAcl : {BUILTIN\Users: AccessAllowed (ChangePermissions, CreateDirectories,
                   ExecuteKey, GenericAll, GenericExecute, GenericWrite, ListDirectory,
                   ReadExtendedAttributes, ReadPermissions, TakeOwnership, Traverse,
                   WriteData, WriteExtendedAttributes, WriteKey)}
SystemAcl        : {}
```

Each `ACE-string` in the `DACL` follows the structure of

```
ace_type;ace_flags;rights;object_guid;inherit_object_guid;account_sid;(resource_attribute)
```

See [MS Learn - ACE Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/ace-strings)

**Constructing an ACE**

So, we want to add additional `ACE-strings` into the `DACL` (or change, remove or replace).
This might be done by changing the `SDDL` using string manipulation. But I don't know how to integrate the `SDDL` back into a .Net object in that way.

The relevant fields for adding an ACE to a DACL are:

- ace_type: Indicates the type of ACE (e.g., A for access allowed, D for access denied).
- ace_flags: Flags specifying inheritance and other properties.
- rights: Specifies the access rights granted or denied.
- account_sid: The Security Identifier (SID) of the user or group.

The order of these fields matters.

Example ACE string for granting access to a specific user:

```
(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-32-545)
```

- A: Access allowed.
- GA: Grant all permissions.
- S-1-5-32-545 (Well known SID for BUILTIN\Users)

Now, when the basics are set, is where the answers from above makes an entry using some .Net magic.

And actually, the `RawDescriptor` is already available using the `ConvertFrom-SddlString` cmdlet.

```
$sddl = ConvertFrom-SddlString "O:LAG:BUD:(A;;RPWPCCDCLCSWRCWDWOGA;;;S-1-5-32-545)"


$sddl.RawDescriptor

IsContainer                 : False
IsDS                        : False
ControlFlags                : DiscretionaryAclPresent, SelfRelative
Owner                       : S-1-5-21-XXXXXXX-500
Group                       : S-1-5-32-545
SystemAcl                   :
DiscretionaryAcl            : {System.Security.AccessControl.CommonAce}
IsSystemAclCanonical        : True
IsDiscretionaryAclCanonical : True
BinaryLength                : 96


$sddl.RawDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl

BinaryLength       : 24
AceQualifier       : AccessAllowed
IsCallback         : False
OpaqueLength       : 0
AccessMask         : 269353023
SecurityIdentifier : S-1-5-32-545
AceType            : AccessAllowed
AceFlags           : None
IsInherited        : False
InheritanceFlags   : None
PropagationFlags   : None
AuditFlags         : None
```

Constructing a bare `ACE`-object can be done as the other answers here. But the example is incomplete and my knowledge of .Net doesn't permit me to find out what's missing :/

The other option provided above, is working with a `SecurityDescriptor` object instead. Which is already provided for us in the `RawDescriptor` :)

```
$sddl.RawDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess("Allow", "S-1-5-32-546", 268435456,"None","None")

$sddl.RawDescriptor.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All)

O:LAG:BUD:(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPRCWDWOGA;;;BU)(A;;GA;;;BG)
```

```
DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess(accessType, sid, rule)
```

**accessType**

'Allow' 0
The AccessRule object is used to allow access to a secured object.

'Deny'  1
The AccessRule object is used to deny access to a secured object.

**sid**

This we know.

**rule**

The mystery...

```
ObjectAccessRule(IdentityReference, Int32, Boolean, InheritanceFlags, 
PropagationFlags, Guid, Guid, AccessControlType)
```

See [MS Learn - DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.discretionaryacl.addaccess?view=net-8.0)

The thing missing, is how to construct the mask which lurks in [MS Learn - ObjectAccessRule Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.objectaccessrule?view=net-8.0)

**A solution**

The mask could of course be copied from an already existing `ACE` and used when registering the configured session.

In the code below I'm cloning the mask for the special user `INTERACTIVE` (S-1-5-4).

```
$SID = '<Enter SID here>'

$PlainConfig = Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name microsoft.powershell

$PlainSDDL = ConvertFrom-SddlString $PlainCfg.SecurityDescriptorSddl

$PlainMask = ($PlainSDDL.RawDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl |
  where SecurityIdentifier -eq 'S-1-5-4').AccessMask

$PlainSDDL.RawDescriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess(
  'Allow',
  $SID,
  $PlainMask,
  'None',
  'None
)

$MySDDL = $PlainSDDL.RawDescriptor.GetSddlForm(
  [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All
)

Register-PsSessionConfiguration `
  -Name 'MySession' `
  -SecurityDescriptionSddl $MySDDL
```

I will get back on actual mask construction if I ever learn how to...

**Setting Configured Session permissions using GUI**

When constructing a `Security Descriptor` for usage with `WINRM`, there is actually a graphical tool for that.

```
Register-PSSessionConfiguration -Name 'SessionTest' -ShowSecurityDescriptorUI


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Plugin

Type            Keys                                Name
----            ----                                ----
Container       {Name=SessionTest}                  SessionTest
```

Just add the appropriate group or user to the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/<SessionName>` object

[image: Permission Control Box]

[image: Permission Control Box with added group]

```
Get-PSSessionConfiguration -Name 'SessionTest'


Name          : SessionTest
PSVersion     : 5.1
StartupScript :
RunAsUser     :
Permission    : NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE AccessAllowed, 
                BUILTIN\Administrators AccessAllowed, 
                EXAMPLEHOST\EnterMyConfiguredSessionGroup AccessAllowed
```